# Dart Unhandled Exception: type <String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm a new flutter user, this time I encountered a problem when I wanted to display data from JSON to flutter, the error occurred when I created a group in JSON, an example of a group that I created is like this or this link JSON

> https://fleetime-sigma.herokuapp.com/debiturs

[image]

After I created the group and there was an error like the following

> E/flutter (22640): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart
> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is
> not a subtype of type 'List', stack trace: #0
> MstdebiturApiService.getNasabah
> (package:flutter_auth/network/nasabah_service.dart:17:21) E/flutter
> (22640):  E/flutter (22640): #1
> _FutureBuilderState._subscribe. (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:627:33) E/flutter (22640):

[image]

Whereas previously without groups there were no errors and the data could appear, here's my source snippet

**service_nasabah.dart**

```
class MstdebiturApiService {
  final String apiUrl = 'https://fleetime-sigma.herokuapp.com';

  // Get Nasabah
  Future<List<Mstdebitur>> getNasabah() async {
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('$apiUrl/debiturs'))
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
      throw Exception('Timeout');
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<Mstdebitur> mstdebitur =
      body.map((dynamic item) => Mstdebitur.fromJson(item)).toList();
      return mstdebitur;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load mstdebitur list');
    }
  }

  // Get Nasabah by id
  Future<Mstdebitur> getNasabahById(String nik) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$apiUrl/debiturs/$nik'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Mstdebitur mstdebitur = Mstdebitur.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      return mstdebitur;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load mstdebitur');
    }
  }
```

and view to flutter
**list_debitur.dart**

```
class ListDebitur extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Mstdebitur> mstdebitur;
  ListDebitur({Key key,  this.mstdebitur}) : super(key: key);
  final MstdebiturApiService api = MstdebiturApiService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: mstdebitur == null ? 0 : mstdebitur.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
              shape: Border(left: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 5)),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          mstdebitur[index].nama_debitur,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          mstdebitur[index].alamat,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          mstdebitur[index].relationship,
                        ),
                        Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ElevatedButton.icon(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                          title: Text('Hapus Data Nasabah'),
                                          content: Text(
                                              'Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data nasabah ini?'),
                                          actions: [
                                            TextButton(
                                                child: Text('hapus'),
                                                onPressed: () async {
                                                  api.deleteNasabah(mstdebitur[index].nik);
                                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                }
                                            ),
                                            TextButton(
                                                child: Text('tidak'),
                                                onPressed: () async {
                                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                                }
                                            )
                                          ]));
                                },
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.red,
                                ),
                                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                label: Text('Hapus'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton.icon(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          DetailDebitur(mstdebitur: mstdebitur[index]),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                                label: Text(
                                  'Detail',
                                ),
                              )
                            ]),
                      ])));
        });
  }
}
```

Class Mstdebitur

```
class Mstdebitur {
  // int id;
  // String nama_debitur;
  // String alamat;
  // String no_telp;
  // String no_ktp;
  // String no_selular;
  String id;
  String no_debitur;
  int nik;
  String nama_debitur;
  String alamat;
  String tempat_lahir;
  String tanggal_lahir;
  String pekerjaan;
  String instansi;
  String agama;
  String gender;
  String no_telp;
  String no_selular;
  String email;
  String nama_ibu;
  String relationship;
  String nama_pasangan;
  String perkejaan_pasangan;
  String tgl_lahir_pasangan;
  String tempat_lahir_pasangan;
  int nik_pasangan;
  String total_income;
  String bidang_usaha;
  int jumlah_tanggungan;
  String provinsi;
  String kabupaten;
  String kecamatan;
  String kelurahan;
  int rt;
  int rw;
  int kodepos;
  Mstdebitur({
    // this.id = 0,
    // this.nama_debitur,
    // this.alamat,
    // this.no_telp,
    // this.no_ktp,
    // this.no_selular,
    this.id,
    this.no_debitur,
    this.nik = 0,
    this.nama_debitur,
    this.alamat,
    this.tempat_lahir,
    this.tanggal_lahir,
    this.pekerjaan,
    this.instansi,
    this.agama,
    this.gender,
    this.no_telp,
    this.no_selular,
    this.email,
    this.nama_ibu,
    this.relationship,
    this.nama_pasangan,
    this.perkejaan_pasangan,
    this.tgl_lahir_pasangan,
    this.tempat_lahir_pasangan,
    this.nik_pasangan = 0,
    this.total_income,
    this.bidang_usaha,
    this.jumlah_tanggungan = 0,
    this.provinsi,
    this.kabupaten,
    this.kecamatan,
    this.kelurahan,
    this.rt = 0,
    this.rw = 0,
    this.kodepos = 0,
  });

  factory Mstdebitur.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Mstdebitur(
        // id: json["id"],
        // nama_debitur: json["nama_debitur"],
        // alamat: json["alamat"],
        // no_telp: json["no_telp"],
        // no_ktp: json["no_ktp"],
        // no_selular: json["no_selular"],
        id: json["id"],
        no_debitur: json["no_debitur"],
        nik: json["nik"],
        nama_debitur: json["nama_debitur"],
        alamat: json["alamat"],
        tempat_lahir: json["tempat_lahir"],
        tanggal_lahir: json["tanggal_lahir"],
        pekerjaan: json["pekerjaan"],
        instansi: json["instansi"],
        agama: json["agama"],
        gender: json["gender"],
        no_telp: json["no_telp"],
        no_selular: json["no_selular"],
        email: json["email"],
        nama_ibu: json["nama_ibu"],
        relationship: json["relationship"],
        nama_pasangan: json["nama_pasangan"],
        perkejaan_pasangan: json["perkejaan_pasangan"],
        tgl_lahir_pasangan: json["tgl_lahir_pasangan"],
        tempat_lahir_pasangan: json["tempat_lahir_pasangan"],
        nik_pasangan: json["nik_pasangan"],
        total_income: json["total_income"],
        bidang_usaha: json["bidang_usaha"],
        jumlah_tanggungan: json["jumlah_tanggungan"],
        provinsi: json["provinsi"],
        kabupaten: json["kabupaten"],
        kecamatan: json["kecamatan"],
        kelurahan: json["kelurahan"],
        rt: json["rt"],
        rw: json["rw"],
        kodepos: json["kodepos"],
      );

  factory Mstdebitur.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => Mstdebitur(
        // id: map["id"],
        // nama_debitur: map["nama_debitur"],
        // alamat: map["alamat"],
        // no_telp: map["no_telp"],
        // no_ktp: map["no_ktp"],
        // no_selular: map["no_selular"],
        id: map["id"],
        no_debitur: map["no_debitur"],
        nik: map["nik"],
        nama_debitur: map["nama_debitur"],
        alamat: map["alamat"],
        tempat_lahir: map["tempat_lahir"],
        tanggal_lahir: map["tanggal_lahir"],
        pekerjaan: map["pekerjaan"],
        instansi: map["instansi"],
        agama: map["agama"],
        gender: map["gender"],
        no_telp: map["no_telp"],
        no_selular: map["no_selular"],
        email: map["email"],
        nama_ibu: map["nama_ibu"],
        relationship: map["relationship"],
        nama_pasangan: map["nama_pasangan"],
        perkejaan_pasangan: map["perkejaan_pasangan"],
        tgl_lahir_pasangan: map["tgl_lahir_pasangan"],
        tempat_lahir_pasangan: map["tempat_lahir_pasangan"],
        nik_pasangan: map["nik_pasangan"],
        total_income: map["total_income"],
        bidang_usaha: map["bidang_usaha"],
        jumlah_tanggungan: map["jumlah_tanggungan"],
        provinsi: map["provinsi"],
        kabupaten: map["kabupaten"],
        kecamatan: map["kecamatan"],
        kelurahan: map["kelurahan"],
        rt: map["rt"],
        rw: map["rw"],
        kodepos: map["kodepos"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        // "id": id,
        // "nama_debitur": nama_debitur,
        // "alamat": alamat,
        // "no_telp": no_telp,
        // "no_ktp": no_ktp,
        // "no_selular": no_selular,
        "id": id,
        "no_debitur": no_debitur,
        "nik": nik,
        "nama_debitur": nama_debitur,
        "alamat": alamat,
        "tempat_lahir": tempat_lahir,
        "tanggal_lahir": tanggal_lahir,
        "pekerjaan": pekerjaan,
        "instansi": instansi,
        "agama": agama,
        "gender": gender,
        "no_telp": no_telp,
        "no_selular": no_selular,
        "email": email,
        "nama_ibu": nama_ibu,
        "relationship": relationship,
        "nama_pasangan": nama_pasangan,
        "perkejaan_pasangan": perkejaan_pasangan,
        "tgl_lahir_pasangan": tgl_lahir_pasangan,
        "tempat_lahir_pasangan": tempat_lahir_pasangan,
        "nik_pasangan": nik_pasangan,
        "total_income": total_income,
        "bidang_usaha": bidang_usaha,
        "jumlah_tanggungan": jumlah_tanggungan,
        "provinsi": provinsi,
        "kabupaten": kabupaten,
        "kecamatan": kecamatan,
        "kelurahan": kelurahan,
        "rt": rt,
        "rw": rw,
        "kodepos": kodepos,
      };

  @override
  String toString() {
    //   return 'Nasabah{id: $id, nama_debitur: $nama_debitur, alamat: $alamat, no_telp: $no_telp, no_ktp: $no_ktp, no_selular: $no_selular}';
    // }
    return 'Mstdebitur{'
        'id: $id, no_debitur: $no_debitur , nik: $nik, nama_debitur: $nama_debitur, alamat: $alamat, tempat_lahir: $tempat_lahir, tanggal_lahir: $tanggal_lahir'
        'pekerjaan: $pekerjaan, instansi: $instansi, agama: $agama, gender: $gender, no_telp: $no_telp, no_selular: $no_selular'
        'email: $email, nama_ibu: $nama_ibu, relationship: $relationship, nama_pasangan: $nama_pasangan, perkejaan_pasangan: $perkejaan_pasangan, tgl_lahir_pasangan: $tgl_lahir_pasangan'
        'tempat_lahir_pasangan: $tempat_lahir_pasangan, nik_pasangan: $nik_pasangan, total_income: $total_income, bidang_usaha: $bidang_usaha, jumlah_tanggungan: $jumlah_tanggungan, provinsi: $provinsi'
        'kabupaten: $kabupaten, kecamatan: $kecamatan, kelurahan: $kelurahan, rt: $rt, rw: $rw, kodepos: $kodepos}';
  }
}

class MstdebiturResult {
  String status;
  List<Mstdebitur> data = <Mstdebitur>[];
  MstdebiturResult({
    this.status,
    this.data,
  });
  factory MstdebiturResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) => MstdebiturResult(
        status: data["status"],
        data: List<Mstdebitur>.from(
            data["data"].map((item) => Mstdebitur.fromJson(item))),
      );
}

MstdebiturResult mstdebiturResultFromJson(String jsonData) {
  final data = json.decode(jsonData);
  return MstdebiturResult.fromJson(data);
}

String mstdebiturToJson(Mstdebitur mstdebitur) {
  final jsonData = mstdebitur.toJson();
  return json.encode(jsonData);
}
```

please help me, thanks you sir!!

error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body)
```

I think this line causing problem for you . Make the body as final and use as follows

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
  List<Mstdebitur> mstdebitur =
  body['data'].map((dynamic item) => Mstdebitur.fromJson(item)).toList();
  return mstdebitur;
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load mstdebitur list');
}
```

**update**

in your Mstdebitur.fromJson() you are storing id as Stirng ,but from your json it came as an int

use this,

```
 id: json["id"].toString()
```

Or change your 'id' to an int

Comment: when i change to final body = jsonDecode(response.body) ERROR -> Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => Mstdebitur' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) =>

Comment: Can you please show.. log of your response.body and Mstdebitur class

Comment: error after change your source, this error i have update my post

Comment: it is a issue in  type convertion were you try to store a int value from json as String , check your modal class fromJson method

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm confused :D

Comment: check my answer please, if you get an issue again cross check the type of data form json and your Modelclass